# datatable to .xsd table with C#

Tags: c#, datatable

I can assign .xsd table to a datatable but I have problem assigning datatable loaded from file to .xsd table.

Could anyone please let me know how to assign datatable to .xsd.table or suggests a good article.

Thanks

Comment: Like http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317940 ?

Comment: @MarcGravell: I already found that article but I am not using any database, Thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure that is required. If your DataTable has columns etc, it should be fine. Btw, what is the incentive to use DataTable here?

Comment: .xsd table meaning a [strongly typed dataset](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320714)? Or did you have something else in mind?